# /usr/bin/MAKE simultaneously present and not present

Tags: macos, zsh

I'm using macOS Monterey 12.0.1. When I run the Terminal app, it informs me "The default interactive shell is now zsh." Okay.

Today I ran `make` to build a program, except my caps lock was on and so I typed `MAKE`. Surprisingly, it worked!

So I checked and there indeed was an all-caps `MAKE`:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/MAKE
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  137696 Oct 17 23:30 /usr/bin/MAKE
```

Interesting! So maybe macOS has some all-caps variants of common utilities? I decided to check for other possibilities:

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ ls [A-Z]*
AssetCacheLocatorUtil       DeRez               IOMFB_FDR_Loader        SafeEjectGPU
AssetCacheManagerUtil       GetFileInfo         ResMerger           SetFile
AssetCacheTetheratorUtil    IOAccelMemory           Rez             SplitForks
```

Wait a minute... where is `MAKE`?

```
$ ls -l MAKE
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  137696 Oct 17 23:30 MAKE
```

Still there.

```
$ ls -l M*
ls: M*: No such file or directory
```

Not there!

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? Is it somehow a file that's hidden from normal `ls` and shell file name globbing? Even `ls -a` doesn't show it.

Comment: macOS is generally not case-sensitive, but it is case-aware. Did you just try looking in `usr/bin/` to see what was there? [btw, get 12.1, 12.0.1 was horribly buggy]

Comment: That's a shrodinger cat symdrom  I think it's because the files are not case sensible, and so if you search for MaKe MAKe or mAKe it should also work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, macOS creates filesystems that are case-preserving but not case-sensitive. So "MAKE" matches "make".

If you would prefer strict case sensitivity, you'll need to use Disk Utility to create a case-sensitive APFS filesystem and install macOS onto that.

**Edited to add:**
Also note that globbing (e.g. `ls /usr/bin/M*`) works differently than specifying an exact filename (e.g. `ls /usr/bin/MAKE`) because in the former case, the shell is asking for a directory listing and then doing the matching itself, so it follows `bash`'s normal case-sensitive globbing rules, but in the latter case, it's asking the OS's filesystem APIs to match an exact filename, so macOS's filesystem APIs do their non-case-sensitive matching in that case.

Comment: Ah, you're right. It did occur to me that it was a Mac case-sensitivity issue, so I checked with `ls` and didn't see `ls`...  but of course `ls` is `/bin/ls` and not `/usr/bin/ls` so that's why it didn't work.

Comment: I think I even tried running `LS` (all caps) but I did `/usr/bin/LS` instead of just `LS`.

Comment: Also I probably should have thought more about how `ls` actually works. It probably just calls `stat` on whatever filenames it gets from the shell, so it doesn't really know if the file is `make` or `MAKE` or whatever as long as `stat` works.